# Sorting a list inside dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has student names as the key and then a list with 3 scores from a test stored inside.

I need to output the keys in alphabetical order as well as having the list sorted in order high to low.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

```
def task3():
    import pprint
    classList = {}
    classSearch = input("Which class would you like to interrogate? ")
    try:
        with open("answers " + classSearch + ".txt", 'rb') as handle:
            classList = pickle.loads(handle.read())
    except IOError as error:
        print ("Sorry, this file does not exist")

    sortOption = int(input("Would you like sort the students in alphabetical order? Enter 1"))
    if sortOption == 1:

        #how do I sort the list in order, I guess I have to for loop over the dictionary to then be able to access the keys
        pprint.pprint(classList)
```

Comment: What is the problem of you code?

Comment: I want to be able to sort the list which stored in a key before outputting the students in alphabetical order with their 3 scores ordered high to low

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want to achieve :

```
dictionary = {'Louis': [2, 10, 1],
               'John': [6, 1, 16]
               }
for name in sorted(dictionary.keys()):
    print name
    print sorted(dictionary[name], reverse=True)
```

The output :

```
John
[16, 6, 1]
Louis
[10, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Fun fact: `sorted(dictionary.keys()) == sorted(dictionary)`

Comment: Yep, you're right, thanks for the fact :). However I prefer specifying it for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'foo1':[1, 2, 4], 'foo': [100, 123, 321]}
x = sorted(d.items())
for key, value in x:
    value.sort()
    value.reverse()
print x

  >>> 
[('foo', [100, 123, 321]), ('vishnu', [1, 2, 4])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries are unsorted data structures. One of the caveit is:

```
for sorted_key in sorted(classList.keys()):
  print sorted_key, sorted(classList[sorted_key], reverse=True)
```

Here you extract keys from the dictionary and sort them. Next step is sorting list values for the given key.